# continuity of multi-variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

i got a little bit out of practice and dont really remember if this is right.
i got a function 
\begin{align}
F:(0,\infty)\times S_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
(t,x)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
t^b x_1+x_2 \log t\\
t^b x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $S_1$ is the unitcircle and $b$ a constant. and i need to know if F and the reverse functions both are continuous. Is this clearly true cause both cooridnates are obvious continuous or is there more behind it??

Comment: I suppose here you are parametrizing $t$ by e.g. $(\cos t, \sin t)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: oh sorry i failed some things, i did edit it.